# Why is animating on event trigger causing an endless animation loop in OpenLayers 6.5?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I have the following OpenLayers map:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-92.5, 38]),
      zoom: 5
    })
  });
  map.on('postcompose', function(e) {
    map.getView().animate({
      zoom: map.getView().getZoom() + 1,
      duration: 2000
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
</script>
```

My intention is for this map to load itself and then automatically zoom itself in one level. Instead, this map loads itself and then endlessly zooms itself in one level at a time.

My initial theory was that each time the map zoomed it triggered another 'postcompose' event, causing it to zoom again. I've been trying to follow the RenderEvents documentation, and it seems like either the preventDefault() or stopPropagation() method might do what I want, but my understanding of JavaScript is limited at best and I'm not sure if I've implemented the method correctly, or if this is even in fact the problem.

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_render_Event-RenderEvent.html

Can anyone tell me how I can prevent my map from zooming in endlessly on itself when it loads, and instead only zoom itself one time?

Comment: Use `map.once('postcompose',`  so oy stops after the first event.

Comment: I'm not sure how to mark your comment as the answer, but it is indeed the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use `.once()` to listen for only the next occurrence of an event, so

```
map.once('postcompose', function(e){
  ...
});
```

will stop after the first event and only re-render once.